# Matching Multiple Patterns in One Line

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please tell me why my pattern: `<p(\s+(.*)?)?>(.[^</p>]*)?</p>` does not work correctly. Example matches:

> 1. `<p>This is a test and anything can be here even other <tags>tags</tags></p>`
> 2. `<p style="test">This is a test</p>`
> 3. `<p></p>`

And if the above were all on one line it should find 3 separate patterns. The link below demonstrates its true behaviour which is very odd...

http://regexr.com?33jrn

The matches it finds should always immediately start when it finds `<p` and immediately stop when it finds `</p>`

Comment: Do you want this - http://regexr.com?33jrq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your regex. Let's see what they look like.

Here's your regex: -

```
<p(\s+(.*)?)?>(.[^</p>]*)?</p>
```

- **Problem 1: -** Notice the pattern `(.*)?`. It is not doing what you think. It is not a enforcing a reluctant behaviour on `*` quantifier. Rather it's a enforcing an optional quantifier `(?)` over a greedy `*` quantifier. It simply means match `0 or 1` repetition of `(.*)`. For making it reluctant, you need to move `?` inside the bracket. So, you need to use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)?`.
- **Problem 2: -** `[^</p>]` does not negate `</p>` rather it negates - `<, /, p, >` as separate characters. Note that in a character class, each character is taken literally. There is not grouping in there. So, `(.[^</p>]*)` means match a `character` if is not followed by `0 or more repetition` of either of `[</p>]`. That is not what you want. If you want to match a sequence that is not `</p>`, then you can use a negative look-ahead like this:  - `((?!</p>).)*`. Now this will check first whether the following sequence is not `</p>`, then it matches the next character.

So, your regex pattern should be: -

```
<p(\s+(.*?))?>((?!</p>).)*</p>
```

Or, you can even simplify your regex to: -

```
<p[^>]*>((?!</p>).)*</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p.*?>.*?</p>
```

Please read about greedy and reluctant on this page: "[Differences Among Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `(.[^</p>]*)?`, which means:

- a single char
- followed by any char n times but not a `<`, neither a `/`, nor a `p` and nor a `>`

I guess you wanted to mean *not the `</p>` string n times*, but this is not the way to do it.

Try with `.*?` instead: `<p(\s+(.*)?)?>.*?</p>`.

While `.*` means *match the longest string*, `.*?` means *match the shortest string*.

For example, for the string `#foo#bar#`, `.*` will match `#foo#bar#` while `.*?` will match `#foo#`.